# Session Windows (Context) in Esper

Tags: esper

I'm looking for a way to group or window Esper events in a dynamic window, in a similar as to what Apache Flink  call's Session Windows (see below)

[image: Session Windows]

I'd like to create a Contex per session, but so far have been unable to accomplish a way to capture sessions. Initial (not working) example;

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA EventX AS (sensorId string, timestamp long, value double);

CREATE SCHEMA SessionEvent AS (sensorId string, totalValue double, events EventX[]);

-- Unsure about Context definition
CREATE CONTEXT sensorSessionCtx
 CONTEXT sensorCtx PARTITION BY sensorId FROM EventX,
 CONTEXT sessionCtx INITITATED BY Eventx TERMINATED BY pattern [every EventX -> (timer:interval(3 sec) and not EventX)];

CONTEXT sensorSessionCtx
INSERT INTO SessionEvent
SELECT sensorId
,      SUM(value) AS totalValue
,      window(*)  AS events
FROM   EventX#keepall
OUTPUT LAST WHEN TERMNATED;

@Name('Sessions') SELECT * FROM   SessionEvent;
```

And some testdata for [Esper EPL Online](http://esper-epl-tryout.appspot.com/epltryout/mainform.html)

```
EventX = {sensorId='A', timestamp=0, value=1.1}
t=t.plus(1 seconds)
EventX = {sensorId='A', timestamp=1000, value=3.2}
t=t.plus(1 seconds)
EventX = {sensorId='B', timestamp=2000, value=8.4}
t=t.plus(1 seconds)
EventX = {sensorId='A', timestamp=3000, value=2.7}
EventX = {sensorId='B', timestamp=3000, value=0.2}
t=t.plus(3 seconds)
EventX = {sensorId='A', timestamp=6000, value=3.1}
```

Expected output;

```
SessionEvent={sensorId='A', totalValue=7.0, events={[EventX={sensorId='A', timestamp=0, value=1.1},EventX={sensorId='A', timestamp=1000, value=3.2},EventX={sensorId='A', timestamp=3000, value=2.7}]}}
SessionEvent={sensorId='B', totalValue=8.6, events={[EventX={sensorId='B', timestamp=2000, value=8.4},EventX={sensorId='B', timestamp=3000, value=0.2}]}}
SessionEvent={sensorId='A', totalValue=3.1, events={[EventX={sensorId='A', timestamp=6000, value=3.1}]}}
```

How would I create (dynamic) session windows (or contexts) in Esper?

Comment: Maybe state what is not working..., does it not run, is the output incorrect, or what

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide a Session-context in Esper, we need to create a [Nested Context](http://esper.espertech.com/release-4.11.0/esper-reference/html/context.html#context_nesting).

In this nested context we [Keyed Segment](http://esper.espertech.com/release-4.11.0/esper-reference/html/context.html#context_def_keyed) context is defined first, to 'split' to stream into separate *user*, or *sensor* as per the example, streams. We then define a second [Non-Overlapping](http://esper.espertech.com/release-4.11.0/esper-reference/html/context.html#context_def_nonoverlapping) context. The second context will only operate within the first keyed context and (thus all events in this context have the same *sensorId*).

```sql
CREATE CONTEXT sensorSessionCtx
  CONTEXT sensorCtx
    PARTITION BY sensorId FROM EventX
, CONTEXT sessionCtx
    START EventX
    END pattern [every (timer:interval(3 sec) AND NOT EventX)];
```

In the example, the output with this context definition would be;

```
At: 2001-01-01 08:00:06.000
  Insert
    SessionEvent={sensorId='A', totalValue=7.000000000000001, events={[EventX={sensorId='A', timestamp=0, value=1.1},EventX={sensorId='A', timestamp=1000, value=3.2},EventX={sensorId='A', timestamp=3000, value=2.7}]}}
  Insert
    SessionEvent={sensorId='B', totalValue=8.6, events={[EventX={sensorId='B', timestamp=2000, value=8.4},EventX={sensorId='B', timestamp=3000, value=0.2}]}}

At: 2001-01-01 08:00:09.000
  Insert
    SessionEvent={sensorId='A', totalValue=3.1, events={[EventX={sensorId='A', timestamp=6000, value=3.1}]}}
```

Although note that, when the internal engine timer has been disabled, for the last window to ever terminate, an event (any kind will do) should be received with a timestamp greater than the last session event timestamp + the *session gap*. In the EPL Online tool this can be accomplished by adding `t=t.plus(10 seconds)` after the last defined input event. This is especially important should you want to create any kind of unit-test

```scala
val finalEventTimestamp = Long.MaxValue - 1 //Note: Long.MaxValue won't trigger final evaluation!
engine.getEPRuntime.sendEvent(new CurrentTimeEvent(finalEventTimestamp))
```

Answer (score 0):

One could also do this.

```
CREATE CONTEXT sensorSessionCtx
  initiated by distinct(sensorId) EventX as ex 
  terminated by pattern [every (timer:interval(3 sec) and not EventX(sensorId=ex.sensorId))];

CONTEXT sensorSessionCtx
SELECT sensorId
,      SUM(value) AS totalValue
,      window(*)  AS events
FROM   EventX(sensorId=context.ex.sensorId)#keepall
OUTPUT WHEN TERMiNATED;
```

This now forgets about "sensorId" values which is useful if your space of sensorId values is endless. Otherwise if you have "partition by sensorId" that means the engine tracks all sensorIds at all time.

There is no need for "select * from SessionEvent" so I left it out.

If the output doesn't need to have events you remove #keepall i.e. `CONTEXT sensorSessionCtx SELECT sensorId, sum(value) AS totalValue FROM EventX(sensorId=context.ex.sensorId) OUTPUT SNAPSHOT WHEN TERMINATED;`

EDIT:
Should be "every (timer:interval(3 sec) and not EventX(sensorId=ex.sensorId))" in the termination. The previous suggestion was wrong since the initiating event never counts towards the terminating event/pattern (thus EventX -> every(...) was wrong).

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, although these statement never output anything in both the Online EPL environment as well as in an actual Java solution - like the engine is in an endless loop. Also, your proposed solution would not match the specification of a _session window_ when a single _sensorId_ could have multiple subsequent sessions, each split by a session gap.

Comment: Fixed the termination. The initiating event does not also apply to the termination so the termination should not look for another EventX.

Comment: Try the updated one, it should match session window behavior, or explain why you think it doesn't. I did test against the Online EPL cloud app and that cloud app seems a little slow at times currently.